# Uncaught Error: No version specified facebook sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm updating the **like facebook button** in my website I just followed the instructions in the facebook developer page, I'm getting the following error:

**Uncaught Error: No version specified** 
that's located in the line 82 of the facebook SDK (sdk.js)

the code is the following:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/fan-page-x" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxx&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The like button appears on the page but I get the error in the console.

Comment: I'm guessing you got the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ . I would file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs .

Comment: yes, the code is from the developers page!

Comment: Then file a bug so we can fix the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you don't have another FB JS SDK initialization code in your page.

Comment: If we have another FB JS SDK initiation how to add this? I mean How to add comments and likes