# Invalid version specified, facebook share plugin error

Tags: javascript, facebook, requirejs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to use the facebook share plugin for the web app I am working on, I only need the basic share button. The app uses requirejs for loading javascript, so I followed the [how-to](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/requirejs) and changed the facebook api url to the one found in code snippets on facebook [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/). This doesn't work and the sdk throws error `invalid version specified`. This is how my files look.

**`main.js`**

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'facebookshare' : {
      exports: 'FB'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'facebookshare':  "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0"
 }
});
require(['fb']);
```

**`fb.js`**

```
define(['facebookshare'], function(facebook) {
   document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"></div>';
});
```

What is the best way of including only the facebook share plugin with requirejs?

I referred following questions, but none of them provide a concrete solution. [Uncaught error: no version specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668541/uncaught-error-no-version-specified-facebook-sdk) and [wrong version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019877/fb-init-function-gives-wrong-version-error).

Answer (score 106):

I was also getting the following error *even when using the standard embed code that Facebook provides*.

> **Uncaught Error: invalid version specified** in sdk.js

The first thing to check is that you're including the version number in your `FB.init` call:

```
FB.init({
  appId: 'your-app-id',
  xfbml: true,
  version: 'v2.8'
});
```

---

#### The now-outdated fix...

...was to make a simple tweak and changed the path:

```
From:   //connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js  
To:     //connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js
```

And this fixed the error.  Unfortunately I have no idea why. :-(

Comment: +1 Updating the embed code to have all.js instead of sdk.js worked for me too. Why though!? Considering just putting a filter in WordPress to swap them but that strikes me as a sloppy solution.

Comment: Clarification: I was getting this error when embedding posts with the new embed code, which has a SRC like this: //connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3  

The old embed code doesn't suffer from this issue, but if there's a new one in the same post it breaks the overall JS and neither works.

Comment: you have to specify the version, sdk.js is the new API so : FB.init({
                appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                version    : 'v2.5'

Comment: Documentation for what @bleuscyther said. Thanks! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5

Comment: all.js is deprecated, sdk.js should be used instead (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs), @bleuscyther's solution is the correct one

Comment: At present day, using version : 'v5.0' still triggers the error.

Answer (score 60):

Consider including a `version` parameter to the `src` property as shown below:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8"
```

The default template on [Like button for Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) is incomplete; upon clicking on the "Get Code" button Facebook will generate you a complete template with the `version` parameter included.

Comment: its for the facebook API, why?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because not everyone needs to initiate `FB.init`.

Answer (score 6):

Minor heads up, I had to change

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1`**`&amp;`**`version=v2.8";`

to

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1`**`&`**`version=v2.8";`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when I was changing my file from HTTP to HTTPS. The reason was the lack of specific "HTTP:" or "HTTPS:" in the following code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-width="100%" data-href="//amazingjokes.com/image/2017-03-17/A_good_sign_for_St__Patricks_day" data-num-posts="5"
     data-colorscheme="light">
</div>
```

normally the '//domain.com' copies the scheme we're on, so when you're on htts://example.com a link to '//example2.com' will seen as 'https://example2.com'. For the 'fb-comments' you'll need to specifically state HTTP or HTTPS for the data-href.

Also note that 'https://example.com' according to facebook is another page than 'http://example.com'. So if you upgrade your site for SSL you will lose all past comments if you change the URL in the social plugins from HTTP to HTTPS... The solution I chose was to use HTTP for all older posts, and HTTPS for everything recent

Answer (score 1):

There is (or was) an error in the source code on the [Facebook Share Button Configurator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)! page. If you use the Share Configurator on the page, it should work fine. However there is a code example on the page that says 'Copy & paste the code example to your website...', which is bad code and will result in the button not being visible on your page. The javascript console will show 'Error: invalid version specified'.

I opened a ticket with Facebook in June of 2018 regarding this issue. They have acknowledged that it's a problem with the code and promised to fix the code example, but as of June 17, 2018 the bad code is still there on the site.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the original sdk.js to all.js that resolved my problem :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js"></script>
```

> And carefully change your language for me it's french 'fr_FR'

I took my original script from here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/