# Facebook comments don't appear in extjs container

Tags: javascript, facebook, extjs, facebook-comments

I want to add [Facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) to an extjs container. I created a view that is a container with a div inside:

```
Ext.define('recovery.view.FacebookComment', {

    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'facebook-comments',

    requires: [
        'Ext.container.Container'
    ],

    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        width: '100%',
        height: 300,
        style: {
            borderColor  : 'green',
            borderStyle  : 'dotted'
        },
        autoScroll: true,
        listeners: {
            beforerender: function (container) {
                // Facebook SDK

                var html = '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://recovery.twindb.com" data-width="600" data-numposts="5"></div>';

                (function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                        console.log('SDK is already created:');
                        console.log(d.getElementById(id));
                        return;
                    }
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    // container.update(html);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                Ext.Function.defer(function () {
                    container.update(html);
                }, 1000);
            },
        }
    }]

});
```

I see the SDK is loaded:
[image: Facebook SDK is loaded]

A `<script>` tag is created as well:

[image: script tag]

A `<div>` is created, too:

[image: A div created]

But the comments don't show up:

[image: no comments]

The problem is transient, sometimes the comments do show up, somehow it depends on when the SDK is loaded.

What's a problem here? Any workarounds?

Comment: If you increase the defer time to for example 5000, are the comments always loaded?

Comment: I suspected a timing issues, that's why the defer(). However it doesn't help. In fact , it prints "SDK already created", - I load the SDK before for a "like" button

Comment: If the element is created doesn't mean the script is loaded, right? If you are using Sencha Cmd you can add your script to the js section of app.json. Otherwise you could try load the script in `Ext.Loader.loadScript` in top of your app.js: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript

Comment: That makes sense. However even after 10 seconds the comments don't show up. It's interesting when I add `facebook-comments` to the west region the comments are loaded

Comment: You were getting an error in your console. See my answer for a fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing some fiddles to simulate your problem I noticed that I had the same problem. After some checking and trying I noticed an error in my console that was caused by the facebook sdk js.

```
Error: invalid version specified
```

After some research I found [a solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28578154/408487):

> I made a simple tweak and changed the path:
>
> ```
> From:   //connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js  
> To:     //connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js
> ```

Here you can found a working Sencha Fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11p2
https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/11p2/preview

The code from the Sencha Fiddle:

```
/*
 * I wrote this example using the Ext.Loader object
 */
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: true
});

/*
 * NOTE: I changed sdk.js to all.js to make it work
 * 
 * I was getting an error from facebook sdk: Error: invalid version specified
 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28578154/408487
 */
Ext.Loader.loadScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5');

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            xtype: 'container',
            height: 300,
            style: {
                borderColor  : 'green',
                borderStyle  : 'dotted'
            },

            /* I hate it that I can't use autoEl, but have to add another div through the html property */
            /*autoEl: {
                tag: 'div',
                'data-href': 'https://recovery.twindb.com',
                'data-width': '600',
                'data-numposts': '5'
            },
            componentCls: 'fb-comments',*/
            html: '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://recovery.twindb.com" data-width="600" data-numposts="5"></div>',

            autoScroll: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```